# How to display a video on my lock-screen instead of a wallpaper?

Tags: video, screensaver, screen-lock

I am using Fedora 22. Is there anyway to display a video from a url or from disk storage (preferably muted) on the lock screen?

I use this [tool](http://peterlevi.com/variety/) to change my desktop wallpaper every now and then. It would be cool to have something for the lock-screen as well.

I tried xcreensaver. But there was no such option.

Comment: Look here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2043619

Answer (score 1):

You should try [webnuxsaver](https://github.com/archagy/webnuxsaver).

It allows you to add a list of videos in mp4 and webm format and play them randomly.